# Alignment/spacing improvements to 'Add answer' button in Teams

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stack-overflow-for-teams

When you want to add an answer to a question in Stack Overflow for Teams, you're either greeted by a button with too little space between the icon and the text:

[image: Post Your Answer in Stack Moderators]

or one where the text isn't vertically centered:

[image: Add Another Answer in Stack Moderators]

Other buttons (e.g. Ask Question, and the corresponding buttons on the main site) look fine.

Tested with the latest Safari and Firefox on macOS Mojave 10.14.4.

Comment: Good thing we are all neurotic developers here...

Comment: You're right, this looks a bit off. I'll look into it and see what's happening there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for spotting these. I fixed both and now they're all nice and well-aligned again!